# Seam/JSF/Facelets Compiler or Validator (equivalent of JspC for JSP)

Tags: jsf, seam, richfaces, facelets

Is there such a thing as JspC in the Seam/JSF/Facelets world?

I used the Tomcat's [JspC](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/api/org/apache/jasper/JspC.html) to validate a JSP/Struts application to validate if there are typos in the JSPs or some JSP was calling a Java function that didn't exist, etc. etc.

From time to time I come across bugs in my current project (Seam/Facelets/RichFaces) where it's caused by a typo in action/value binding. And I think bugs like these can be caught using a program. Just wondering if someone has already written one.

Basically a tool that can validate if the method/value binding are correct. I know this would be specially hard in Seam since names are Context sensitive and the tool should somehow figure out what the context is. But I think it should be easier to just check if the names are valid and the Objects bound to those names have the methods and/or properties being referred to in the JSF page.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[JBoss tools](http://www.jboss.org/tools) provides similar functionality.